# Overriding Table names for Arquillian Tests + sql-maven-plugin

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-7, jboss-arquillian, sql-maven-plugin

In our projects we are using entities from an inhouse library (we are using including them as a JAR). The class itself looks something like this (can't paste the real code here).

```
@Table(name = "X_MY_ENTITY")
public class MyEntity{
//columns...
}
```

In our persistence.xml we include a mapping file that maps the table names to our conventions.

```
  <entity class="com.example.MyEntity">
        <table name="REALNAME_MY_ENTITY"/>
        <sequence-generator name="id_seq" sequence-name="REALNAME_MY_ENTITY_SEQ" allocation-size="1"/>
    </entity>
```

Everything works fine.

Now we are using Arquillian for our integration tests and the sql-maven-plugin to generate our schema for the tests. Now I want the plugin to generate a view as well. In the sql-maven-plugin's configuration I include a sql file, where the view is created. This view uses the table mentioned above (eg. `create or replace view EXAMPLE_VIEW as select * from REALNAME_MY_ENTITY`). But when I try to build the project, I get an error: `Table "REALNAME_MY_ENTITY" not found;`

I got my orm.xml (the mapping-fie) in src/test/resources/META-INF/orm.xml, including it to my deployment-package and in my test-persistence.xml

We are using:

- Java 8 + Java EE7
- Open EJB v 7.0.4
- Arquillian JUnit core 1.1.11.Final
- sql-maven-plugin v1.5

How can I configure either Arquillian or the sql-maven-plugin that the mapped table names are used?

Comment: so the view works (sees the table) but the code is not able though it was previously working fine , right? are you sure that the schema name in the test environment is the same as it was working before ?

Comment: or you mean the arquillian is not able to read the orm.xml file ? did u try annotating the entity with @Table*name="REALNAME_MY_ENTITY") just to make sure where is the issue

Comment: I found it: I was looking at the wrong place. Apparently the schema was generated by the hibernate4-maven-plugin and you can configure a mapping file (hibernateMapping). Now the sql-maven-plugin generates the tables with the correct names.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: I was looking at the wrong place. Apparently the schema was generated by the hibernate4-maven-plugin and you can configure a mapping file (hibernateMapping). Now the sql-maven-plugin generates the tables with the correct names.